# ERROR in multi, Module not found: Error: React Hot Loader@next Universal Rendering

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-hot-loader, webpack-hot-middleware, webpack-dev-middleware

I am using

```
"webpack": "^2.4.1",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.2",
"react-hot-loader": "next",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.0",
```

Here is webpack client config entry

```
entry: {
main: [
  'react-hot-loader/patch',
  'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
  './client.js',
],
vendor,
```

},

Here is server/index.js

```
import webpackConfig from '../webpack/webpack.config.client';
const app = express();

const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

app.use(webpackDev(compiler, {
  noInfo: true,
  publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
  serverSideRender: true,
}));

app.use(webpackHot(compiler));
```

Now when I am running server with `npm run build:dev && babel-node -- dist/SSR.js`

I am getting this error.

```
ERROR in multi react-hot-loader/patch webpack-hot-middleware/client ./client.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './client.js' in '/app'
@ multi react-hot-loader/patch webpack-hot-middleware/client ./client.js

ERROR in multi react react-dom redux react-redux react-router-dom react-helmet axios
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react' in '/app'
@ multi react react-dom redux react-redux react-router-dom react-helmet axios

ERROR in multi react react-dom redux react-redux react-router-dom react-helmet axios
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-dom' in '/app'
@ multi react react-dom redux react-redux react-router-dom react-helmet axios

ERROR in multi react react-dom redux react-redux react-router-dom react-helmet axios
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'redux' in '/app'
@ multi react react-dom redux react-redux react-router-dom react-helmet axios
```

Why Webpack Dev middleware is trying to resolve packages in "/app" only.

Thanks for help.